# Lazy loading resource in Laravel, if the method in the model does not return a relation?

Tags: php, laravel

Could you help, me dear colleagues

In Laravel for ApiResource, there is a great function $this->whenLoaded for lazy loading of model relationships https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships.

I have such a problem that I have a property in the model that does not return a relation, but goes to another table in the database, collects apartments by a certain condition, and puts it all in an array (phpMyAdmin designer at the bottom)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebVDn.jpg

In this case, I have addresses and apartments in them are stored by users in a separate field (well, in order not to produce too many addresses, we have Team Lead said that this is the right thing to do and we do it, I am a Junior and still learning \*(ツ)*/)

The code for taking apartments is working and looks like this

**Address.php**

```
public function apartments() {
  return $this->clients->map(function ($item) {
      return $item->apartment;
  })->sort()->flatten();
}
```

I want to make the AdressResource so that it is also lazily loaded via with (or something else, so that the loading mechanism when accessing Adresss:with('apartments')->get()) is something like this (but this naturally does not work).

```
class Address extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "city" => $this->ctiy,
            "street" => $this->address,
            "house" => $this->house,
            $this->corpus ?? "corpus" => $this->corpus,
           ?? this line needs to be lazy, but I can't think of any logic. --> "apartments" => $this->apartments()
        ];
    }
}
```

P.S. relationship many to many it is assumed that the office will serve many addresses and here I think to make a connection after all one to many. Here, as if there are offices and one pack of addresses refers to one office, and another pack to another (well, in short, as in the mail, like some addresses there, and others here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to rewrite the logic to a relationship and i guess that will solve your problem, so you can use ordinary `whenLoaded()` calls.

```
public function apartments() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Apartment::class, 'clients', 'apartment_id', 'client_id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it is a crutch, but the solution is working, I think!
However, I still need to store the addresses in a separate table... What do you think about this?

Comment: Explain why it is a crutch, Eloquent orm wise this is very optimal? where is that extra address column?

Comment: I have apartments stored in the clients table -- > id, name, id_address, apartment.
Addresses are stored in a separate table in the form -- > id, address --> where address contains the country, city, street, and house, separated by commas.

It seems like it is impractical to make a separate table for apartments (so the team leader said and I agree with this decision)

Comment: I have actually worked on an rental managment tool and there we put the adress on the apartment since it never changed? i don't excatcly see the problem and how it ties into this solution being a crutch.

Comment: It's just that a house can have many apartments, and to store it all in one address, somehow it will be wrong, overloaded. We have the id_address of the client and the apartment is stored there (integer --> apartment). So convenient (in my junior opinion), but how to insert all this into ApiResource, so that there is the same convenient lazy loading, since you do not always want to get apartments (in the ideal case, you can of course just ignore this, but I would like to grow a little as a developer)